# Python 3.x - Class instance in shared memory (multiprocessing)

Tags: python-3.x, class, instance, shared-memory

I'm trying to share a class instance between some process in Python (3.6+).

I'm using BaseManager, and I can place a class in shared memory but not an instance, if I try to retrieve it I get a method and not my instance..

**Working example :**

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def test(self):
        print("Hi !")

manager = BaseManager()
manager.register('MyClass', MyClass)
manager.start()
my_class = manager.MyClass()
my_class.test()
```

**What I'm trying to achieve :**

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def test(self):
        print("Hi !")

manager = BaseManager()
manager.register('MyClass', MyClass())
manager.start()
my_class = manager.MyClass
my_class.test()
```

**The error :**

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'test'
```

**Dump of the object retrieved :**

```
<bound method BaseManager.register.<locals>.temp of <multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager object at 0x7f73a3259240>>
```

And obviously, I cannot call any method of my class with this object...

Is there a way to achieve that ?

Thanks !